# JSONObject["name"] not found

Tags: java, json

When I try to get a JSONObject from a JSONArray I get the following error:

> JSONObject["name"] not found.

My code is:

```
System.out.println(jsonArray);
for (int k = 0; k < jsonArray.length(); k++) {
    System.out.println(jsonArray.get(k));
    obt = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(k));
    System.out.println(obt);
    objectName = obt.getString("name");
}
```

The log is:

> 10:47:15,107 INFO  [stdout] (taskScheduler-1)
>   [{"name":"(Id)\|(decimal)","value":"0"}]
>
> 10:47:15,107 INFO  [stdout] (taskScheduler-1)
>   {"name":"(Id)\|(decimal)","value":"0"}
>
> 10:47:15,108 INFO  [stdout] (taskScheduler-1) {}

So I understand that it is not `obt.getString("name")` the problem but `obt = new JSONObject(jsonArray.get(k));`. jsonArray and obt are correctly defined.

Comment: just save `jsonArray.get(k)` directly to `obt`

Comment: It works ! thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just to it like this inside your loop:

```
objectName = jsonArray.get(k).getString("name");
```